# Can't figure out how to loop through getting the char at positions of a string, and convert it

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
function fontGen() {
var userName = document.getElementById("getName").value
var aFonts = ['æ','ɐ','ᴁ','','','','ꪖ','']
var bFonts = ['ɓ', 'ƃ','ᴯ','ᴃ','','','','','','']
var cFonts = ['ƈ','ɔ','ɕ','','匚','','','']
var dFonts = ['đ','ɖ','ɗ','ƌ','ð','ȡ','','Ԃ','','','','','']
var eFonts = ['ǝ', 'ɛ','ɘ','ɚ','','Ⓔ','','','']
var fFonts = ['ƒ','ƭ','ɟ','','','','','']
var gFonts = ['ǥ','ɠ','ƣ','','','','','']
var hFonts = ['ƕ','ħ','','','','ꫝ','']
var iFonts = ['ɨ','ı','','','','']
var jFonts = ['','','','','']
var kFonts = ['ƙ','ʞ','','ⓚ','','','']
var lFonts = ['ł','ƚ','','ｌ','','','']
var mFonts = ['ᵯ','','ⓜ','','','']
var nFonts = ['ɲ','ƞ','ŋ','ᵰ','ռ','','','','']
var oFonts = ['œ','ø','ɵ','ȣ','ʊ','','','','']
var pFonts = ['ƥ','ᵽ','','','','ρ','']
var qFonts = ['ƍ','','','','']
var rFonts = ['ᵲ','','','','','']
var sFonts = ['ƨ','','','','ᦓ','']
var tFonts = ['ʈ','ŧ','','','','']
var uFonts = ['ᵾ','','','','']
var vFonts = ['ʋ','','','','']
var wFonts = ['','','','','᭙','']
var xFonts = ['χ','','','','']
var yFonts = ['ƴ','ƛ','','','']
var zFonts = ['ƶ','ȥ','','']
var char1 = userName.charAt(0)
var char2 = userName.charAt(1)
var char3 = userName.charAt(2)
var char4 = userName.charAt(3)
var char5 = userName.charAt(4)
var char6 = userName.charAt(5)
var char7 = userName.charAt(6)
var char8 = userName.charAt(7)
var char9 = userName.charAt(8)
var char10 = userName.charAt(9)
var chars = [char1, char2, char3, char4, char5, char6, char7, char8,char9, char10]
var alphabet = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
var x =0
var text = ""
var t = 0
var e = 0
for(var i =0; i < 11; i++,x++) {
    while (e < 27) {
        if (chars[x] === alphabet[t]) {
            text = text + chars[x]
            console.log(text)
        } else {
            t++
        }
        e++
    }
}
}
```

I'm trying to loop through the different chars 1-10 but can't seem to figure it out.  I want to get value of each spot, and convert it to the selected font.  Example: `string="abc"` `char1 = string.charAt(0)` `char1 = aFonts[Math.floor(Math.random()*aFonts.length]`

I failed and crashed a few times.

Comment: `while (e < 27) {` You need to reset `e = 0` each time before that loop.

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to do. Can you give an example input and expected output?

Comment: Yes input = a I need to loop so it figures out that it selects random item in array aFonts

Comment: How does your programme crash (error message?)? Did you use your debugger in order to analyse the reason for the crashes?

Comment: I'm using a website complier, the website would freeze then shut, indicating a stuck loop I believe.  Theres no debugger

Comment: @JohnnyMopp I fixed the e=0 problem, but now how do I make the loop so it selects the certain font array

Comment: FYI you don't need all those `charAt` calls, just `chars = userName.split()` to convert the string to an array of characters.

Comment: `let x ="abc§"; let reg=/[^a-z]/gi ; x.replaceAll(reg,'')`     This is your code refactorized with regular expressions.

Comment: Both of you just confused me more

Comment: @Mippy See the answers below. Your task will be greatly simplified if you put all those font arrays in an object/map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i've understood from your question, you are aiming to create a text that is generated from random indexes of those custom font arrays based on the given text.

And this code seems to work for this:

```js
function fontGen() {
  const fontMap = {
    a: ['æ', 'ɐ', 'ᴁ', '', '', '', 'ꪖ', ''],
    b: ['ɓ', 'ƃ', 'ᴯ', 'ᴃ', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
    c: ['ƈ', 'ɔ', 'ɕ', '', '匚', '', '', ''],
    d: ['đ', 'ɖ', 'ɗ', 'ƌ', 'ð', 'ȡ', '', 'Ԃ', '', '', '', '', ''],
    e: ['ǝ', 'ɛ', 'ɘ', 'ɚ', '', 'Ⓔ', '', '', ''],
    f: ['ƒ', 'ƭ', 'ɟ', '', '', '', '', ''],
    g: ['ǥ', 'ɠ', 'ƣ', '', '', '', '', ''],
    h: ['ƕ', 'ħ', '', '', '', 'ꫝ', ''],
    i: ['ɨ', 'ı', '', '', '', ''],
    j: ['', '', '', '', ''],
    k: ['ƙ', 'ʞ', '', 'ⓚ', '', '', ''],
    l: ['ł', 'ƚ', '', 'ｌ', '', '', ''],
    m: ['ᵯ', '', 'ⓜ', '', '', ''],
    n: ['ɲ', 'ƞ', 'ŋ', 'ᵰ', 'ռ', '', '', '', ''],
    o: ['œ', 'ø', 'ɵ', 'ȣ', 'ʊ', '', '', '', ''],
    p: ['ƥ', 'ᵽ', '', '', '', 'ρ', ''],
    q: ['ƍ', '', '', '', ''],
    r: ['ᵲ', '', '', '', '', ''],
    s: ['ƨ', '', '', '', 'ᦓ', ''],
    t: ['ʈ', 'ŧ', '', '', '', ''],
    u: ['ᵾ', '', '', '', ''],
    v: ['ʋ', '', '', '', ''],
    w: ['', '', '', '', '᭙', ''],
    x: ['χ', '', '', '', ''],
    y: ['ƴ', 'ƛ', '', '', ''],
    z: ['ƶ', 'ȥ', '', '']
  }
  const userName = document.getElementById("getName").value
  let customText = ''
  for (let i = 0; i < userName.length; i++) {
    const randomFontIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * fontMap[userName[i]].length)
    customText += fontMap[userName[i]][randomFontIndex]
  }
}
```

- Example input: `cnegfati`
- Output: `ƈŋƣɟɐʈɨ`

Answer (score 0):

Use an object that maps from letters to font arrays. Then look up the character in the object.

```
const font_map = {
    a: aFonts,
    b: bFonts,
    ...
};
let chars = userName.split();
let text = chars.map(c => {
    let font = font_map[c];
    if (font) {
        return font[Math.floor(Math.random()*font.length];
    } else {
        return c;
    }
}).join("");
```

Comment: It's not related to this question but i wanted to ask, is there any particular reason for you to use let instead of const for "chars" and "text" variables?

Comment: Not really. I tend to use `const` for settings, `let` for computed values.